# Kotlin Lazy Initialisation vs Dagger Lazy injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, lazy-initialization

I have a module with a provider method for `OkHttpClient` as such:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
}
```

And another provider method for `Retrofit` as such:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofitBuilder(client: Lazy<OkHttpClient>,gson: Gson): Retrofit {
....
}
```

Now the provider for `Retrofit` takes in a lazily injected `OkHttpClient` which `Dagger` already knows how to create i.e. wrapped with Lazy from `dagger` package. **My question is** would there be a difference in behavior if it is wrapped in Lazy from `dagger` package which from my understanding computes its value on the first call to get() and remembers that same value for all subsequent calls to get() versus when it is wrapped in the Lazy from `kotlin` package which gets the lazily initialized value of the current Lazy instance? Is it even possible to use the Lazy from the `kotlin` package and how would this play out? Do they provide the same behavior?
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and the variant with `kotlin.Lazy` did not compile:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] kotlin.Lazy<? extends com.mycompany.MyClass> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

So no, it's not possible to use `Lazy` from `kotlin` for dependency injection. At least not everywhere.